# In Rails, is there anything 'wrong' with creating a custom controller action for a view that has both 'index' and 'new' functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a simple application where the user can view to-do list items and add new ones. In tutorials, the design is usually the same:

- An 'index' action renders an 'index' view that lists out the to-do items
- A link on the 'index' page, 'Add new to-do item', leads them to a new page for them to add a new item

This doesn't seem like a very good user experience for such simple functionality. I'd like to have the to-do items listed at top (the 'index' part), and on the same page, have a form at bottom to add new to-do items (the 'new' part).

Now that I have two CRUD functionalities on the same page ('index' and 'new'), what would the route be since it's a hybrid of 'index' and 'new'?

It seems to me like I will have to have a custom controller action and view if I want to have multiple CRUD functions on the same page. Is that right, and is there anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there anything 'wrong' with creating a custom controller action for a view that has both 'index' and 'new' functionality?

Yes, it is wrong to create a custom action for this.

On the other hand, putting a form for new element on index page is perfectly fine. CRUD stands for Create,Read,Update,Delete. "new" action is not part of this. It is merely a necessary crutch (you need something to render that form). If you don't want a separate page, have the form right on index page.

Same with edit. If you, for some reason, don't want a separate edit page, you can implement inline-editing. You can see this functionality in many apps.

Comment: Won't he need something like `@todo = Todo.new` in his `index` method in this case?

Comment: @VladBalanescu: Yes, he will need something like that, to support the form builder. But that's implementation detail. The question here is about the concepts and conventions.

Comment: That makes sense, but at what point does cramming functionality into the Index route/action/view become too much? If I have the Index page where the user can view all todos, but also add a new todo, edit todos, and updated todos via AJAX, it seems like that is overdoing it. In that case, where the view is becoming more of a 'dashboard' type page with lots of mixed functionalities, would it warrant a custom route/action/view?

Comment: @Lush: nah. In your case, it's still index page. It displays a list of records. It's just now you have a bit of javascript that enables you to inline-edit data and send updates via ajax or whatever. The updates will, of course, go to `update` action, not index. So I don't see any new functionality that needs to be added to index. But if we were to add, say, block with todo statistics (plot created vs done todos over last week), _then_ it'd become kind of a dashboard. And, as such, it'd belong to its own controller, TodoDashboards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem at all having your own method in `todo_controller.rb`, but you will need to add:

```
match '/todo', to: 'todo#hybridMethod', via: [:get, :post]
```

And then you will have to have your own view which have to match the method name, in my example `hybridMethod.html.erb` under `app/views/todos`. You can copy the code from `index` and `new` methods into your new `hybridMethod`, but don't forget to leave `create` in place, as after you fill in the form the data will get sent to `create` method which will add the entry in the db and redirect if successful. It is not Rails way of doing it, but you can break the rule in this case. I really hope this answers your question!

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right, I will update the answer accordingly.